# Recreating a Parent site in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection

When deleting a parent site in SharePoint Online, it goes to recycle bin.

When I try to recreate the same site, It gives me the error

> Site already exist

and I can't recreate the parent site.

I would appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try deleting it from the first and second stage recycle bin ? Try appending 
?View=2 at the end of your recycle bin URL to go to second stage recycle  bin.

URl should look like,
https:///_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?View=2

Answer (score 0):

there are couple of reason for this issue.

We have received a report that a customer has a **modern group from Outlook Web App** which has the same name as a deleted site collection, when recreating a site collection with the same URL, the issue happens and this site collection doesn't exist in Recycle Bin. Based on this situation, we suggest you first check whether you have a modern group with the same name as a deleted site collection.

If not, go to `SharePoint admin center->Site collection->Recycle Bin` to check them.

Read more over here: https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/404101